# Behaviour of affine transform on 3D image with non-uniform resolution with Scipy

Tags: python, image, scipy, transform, resolution

I'm looking to apply an [affine transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation), defined in homogeneous coordinates on images of different resolutions, but I encounter an issue when one ax is of different resolution of the others.

Normally, as only the translation part of the affine is dependent of the resolution, I normalize the translation part by the resolution and apply the corresponding affine on the image, using scipy.ndimage.affine_transform.

If the resolution of the image is the same for all axes, it works perfectly, you can see below images of the same transformation (being a scale+translation, or rotation+translation, see code below) being applied to an image, its downsampled version (meaning at a lower resolution). Images match (almost) perfectly, differences in voxel values are mainly caused as far as I know by interpolation errors.

But you can see that the shapes overlay between the downsampled transformed image and the transformed (downsampled for comparison) image

[Scale affine transformation applied on the same image, at two different (uniform) resolutions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IzD2.png)

[Rotation affine transformation applied on the same image, at two different (uniform) resolutions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIbMA.png)

Unfortunately, if one of the image axis has a different resolution than the other (see code below), it works well with affine transform with null non-diagonal terms (like translation, or scaling) but the result of the transformation gives a completely wrong result.

[Rotation affine transformation applied on the same image, at two different (non-uniform) resolutions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmFbU.png)

Here you can see a minimal working example of the code:

---

```
import numpy as np
import nibabel as nib
from scipy.ndimage import zoom
from scipy.ndimage import affine_transform
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

################################
#### LOAD ANY 3D IMAGE HERE ####
################################
#%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% TO BE DEFINED BY USER
orig_img = np.zeros((100, 100, 100))
orig_img[25:75, 25:75, 25:75] = 1

ndim = orig_img.ndim

################################
##### DEFINE RESOLUTIONS #######

#%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% TO BE DEFINED BY USER
# Comment/uncomment to choose the resolutions (in mm) of the images
# ORIG_RESOLUTION = [1., 1., 1.]
# TARGET_RESOLUTION = [2., 2., 2.]

ORIG_RESOLUTION = [1., 0.5, 1.]
TARGET_RESOLUTION = [2., 2., 2.]

#####################################
##### DEFINE AFFINE TRANSFORM #######

affine_scale_translation = np.array([[1.5, 0.0, 0.0, -25.],
                                     [0.0, 0.8, 0.0, 0. ],
                                     [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.  ],
                                     [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]])
a = np.sqrt(2)/2.
affine_rotation_translation = np.array([[a  , a  , 0.0, -25.],
                                     [-a , a  , 0.0, 50. ],
                                     [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 ],
                                     [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]])

# #%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% TO BE DEFINED BY USER
# Comment/uncomment to choose the transformation to be applied 

# affine_tf, name_affine = affine_scale_translation, "Tf scale"
affine_tf, name_affine = affine_rotation_translation, "Tf rotation"

######################################################
######## DOWNSAMPLE IMAGE TO LOWER RESOLUTION ########
######################################################

downsample_img = zoom(orig_img,
                      zoom=np.array(ORIG_RESOLUTION)/np.array(TARGET_RESOLUTION),
                      prefilter=False, order=1)

##############################################################################
######## APPLY AFFINE TRANSFORMATION TO ORIGINAL AND DOWNSAMPLE IMAGE ########
##############################################################################

affine_st_full_res, affine_st_low_res = affine_tf.copy(), affine_tf.copy()

# Inverse transform as affine_transform apply the tf from the target space to the original space
affine_st_full_res, affine_st_low_res = np.linalg.inv(affine_st_full_res), np.linalg.inv(affine_st_low_res)

# Normalize translation part (normally expressed in millimeters) for the resolution
affine_st_full_res[:ndim, ndim] = affine_st_full_res[:ndim, ndim] / ORIG_RESOLUTION
affine_st_low_res[:ndim, ndim] = affine_st_low_res[:ndim, ndim] / TARGET_RESOLUTION


# Apply transforms on images of different resolutions

orig_tf_img = affine_transform(orig_img, affine_st_full_res, prefilter=False, order=1)
downsample_tf_img = affine_transform(downsample_img, affine_st_low_res, prefilter=False, order=1)


# Downsample result at full resolution to be compared to result on downsample image

downsample_orig_tf_img = zoom(orig_tf_img, zoom=np.array(
                              ORIG_RESOLUTION)/np.array(TARGET_RESOLUTION),
                              prefilter=False, order=1)

# print(orig_img.shape)
# print(downsample_img.shape)
# print(orig_tf_img.shape)
# print(downsample_orig_tf_img.shape)

###############################
######## VISUALISATION ########
###############################
# We'll visualize in 2D the slice at the middle of the z (third) axis of the image, in both resolution
mid_z_slice_full, mid_z_slice_low = orig_img.shape[2]//2, downsample_img.shape[2]//2

fig, ((ax1, ax2, ax3), (ax4, ax5, ax6)) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=3)

ax1.imshow(orig_img[:, :, mid_z_slice_full], cmap='gray')
ax1.axis('off')
ax1.set_title('1/ Origin image, at full res: {}'.format(ORIG_RESOLUTION))

ax2.imshow(downsample_img[:, :, mid_z_slice_low], cmap='gray')
ax2.axis('off')
ax2.set_title('2/ Downsampled image, at low res: {}'.format(TARGET_RESOLUTION))

ax3.imshow(downsample_tf_img[:, :, mid_z_slice_low], cmap='gray')
ax3.axis('off')
ax3.set_title('3/ Transformed downsampled image')

ax4.imshow(orig_tf_img[:, :, mid_z_slice_full], cmap='gray')
ax4.axis('off')
ax4.set_title('4/ Transformed original image')

ax5.imshow(downsample_orig_tf_img[:, :, mid_z_slice_low], cmap='gray')
ax5.axis('off')
ax5.set_title('5/ Downsampled transformed image')


error = ax6.imshow(np.abs(downsample_tf_img[:, :, mid_z_slice_low] -\
                          downsample_orig_tf_img[:, :, mid_z_slice_low]), cmap='hot')
ax6.axis('off')
ax6.set_title('Error map between 3/ and 5/')

fig.colorbar(error)

plt.suptitle('Result for {} applied on {} and {} resolution'.format(name_affine, ORIG_RESOLUTION, TARGET_RESOLUTION))
plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

---

Comment: Please add a very simple, runnable example. Do not use a complicated image. Just use a maybe 10 x 10 matrix embedded in the example. Add some pattern to the matrix.

Comment: Thank for the input, I've edited the post to add a simple matrix as image input, and I've modified the linked illustrations accordingly

Comment: One of the axes has a different spacing, that's why it does not work. Your matrix is made for axis of equal units. It *might* work if you scale the corresponding column in the matrix. I am quite sure there is a nice mathematical way to express that, try at  https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
I'm aware that the issue is due to th difference of resolution between axis, that's what I have demonstrated with the code. 
I was looking for a solution to modify the transformation accordingly, I've tried scaling the right column but it didnt seem to work, or I havent used the correct ratio.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/612006/decomposing-an-affine-transformation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The downsampling basically changes the basis vectors of the image. This makes the downsampling act like a translation.

But rotation and translation are not commutative (not interchangeable).

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/16719/what-is-the-correct-order-to-multiply-scale-rotation-and-translation-matrices-f

So after your downsampling you have to translate the content of the image back to the original position. Which can be done by composing a affine transformation matrix using `ORIG_RESOLUTION` and applying it before the actual transformation. 
Or use a matrix multipication (e.g. with `np.dot`) to modify the actual transformation.